# psql alternatives to SQL*Plus formatting options

Tags: postgresql

There are formatting options in SQL*Plus like:

```
SET HEADING OFF,SET VERIFY OFF,SET FEEDBACK ON,SET RECSEP OFF,SET PAGESIZE 0
```

Do we have alternate commands for each of the above, available in PSQL?

I just need to migrate my existing code from SQLPLUS towards PSQL.

Answer (score 3):

All formatting options in `psql` are [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

---

`set heading off` would match to `\t`:

> Toggles the display of output column name headings and row count footer. This command is equivalent to \pset tuples_only and is provided for convenience.

---

There is no equivalent to set verify off as psql uses a different way of handling replacement values.

---

`set feedback off` would match to `\set QUIET on`

> Specifies that psql should do its work quietly. By default, it prints welcome messages and various informational output. If this option is used, none of this happens

---

I am not sure what `set recsep off` does exactly, but it sounds as if `\pset recordsep` is the equivalent. But that is only use in unaligned output (toggled through the `\a` option)

---

`set pagesize 0` disables paging if I'm not mistaken. To disable the pager output in `psql` use `\pset pager off`:

> Controls use of a pager program for query and psql help output. If the environment variable PAGER is set, the output is piped to the specified program. Otherwise a platform-dependent default (such as more) is used.
>
> When the pager option is off, the pager program is not used. When the pager option is on, the pager is used when appropriate, i.e., when the output is to a terminal and will not fit on the screen. The pager option can also be set to always, which causes the pager to be used for all terminal output regardless of whether it fits on the screen. \pset pager without a value toggles pager use on and off.

Maybe you need to combine that with `pager_min_lines` but that depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks . That Works